# How to check if a record exist in database or not in sqlite?

Tags: java, android, database, eclipse, sqlite

I'm developing an app with Eclipse. I want to check if the values have been inserted to the database or not to prevent inserting again. If the value is not inserted yet then I want to use the `mySQLiteAdapter.insert();` method to fill the database record, like this:

```
            mySQLiteAdapter.insert("1");
            mySQLiteAdapter.insert("apel");
            mySQLiteAdapter.insert("Peal");
            mySQLiteAdapter.insert("the competitor of samsung");
            mySQLiteAdapter.insert("0");
            mySQLiteAdapter.insert("1");
```

How do I check the if values have been inserted or not?

Comment: Make your column unique, your database will throw an exception if you try to add the same value.

Answer (score 0):

First of all make your id unique and use something similar to this :

```
String sql = "SELECT 1 FROM artist WHERE id=?";
Cursor cursor = mDbHelper.executeSQLQuery(sql, new String[] { Integer.toString(id) });
if (cursor != null) {
            ContentValues artists = new ContentValues();
    if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
        artists.put("id", id);
        artists.put("artist_name", artist_name);
        mDbHelper.insert("artist", null, artists);
        artists.clear();
    }
    cursor.close();
}
```

Of course it will be different depending on the functions in your Database Helper class and the way you are using it. The whole idea is just check if there is a record with that id, if cursor count returns 0 that means there is no record with that id.

The second way you can achieve this is use `REPLACE` statement : `mDbHElper.replace("artist", null, artists);`. It will insert the record if there isn't any with the given primary key. If there is already a record it will update it.

Hope this answer gives you the point how to achieve this and the things you can use.